# Style inheritance in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that a style can be inherited in android via the "parent" property but all the examples I've found are doing this with an Android built-in style. Can I use it with my own styles?

Comment: Have a read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's totally possible to use your own styles as parent. This totally makes sense if you want to provide different themes with the same base theme.

Comment: That is great - what is a code sample of doing this with your own styles?

Comment: Here you find all info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can always use your own styles as a parent, but it's not recommended. From the docs:

> ... you should always inherit your core app styles from the Android Support Library. The styles in the support library provide compatibility with Android 4.0 (API level 14) and higher by optimizing each style for the UI attributes available in each version.

Basically your styles may not be compatible with every version of Android. I recommend using a core style as your root style, and customize it any way you want in child styles.